# Creating a titlepage

Tags: graphics, titles

I want to create a titlepage as the one shown [here](http://www.klinikum.uni-heidelberg.de/fileadmin/medienzentrum/Vorlagen/downloads/090813MZ_BR_SF_Handbuch1.3_ID6189_01.pdf).
But I don't know how to put a line under the logo and get the text and all the stuff in the right position.

I've tried some things with:

```
\begin{titlepage}

\pagecolor{blue}
\includegraphics{logo.jpg}
\title{TITLE}

\end{titlepage}
```

but it's still not looking like the pdf. Any ideas, suggestions or solutions?

Comment: The following site provides two examples where you can start with: http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/title-pages

Comment: Please refer to [this document](http://tug.ctan.org/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf) for some possible options.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Working upon Harish Kumar answer, we can get the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,demo]{report} %% Remove demo in your file.
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Used for dummy text.
\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{1,.60,0,.40}
\definecolor{namecolor}{cmyk}{1,.50,0,.10} % Here I am trying to define the font color that is used in the example but I don't really know which one is it so I leave this to the OP to figure out
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{left=7.5cm} %defines the geometry for the titlepage
\pagecolor{titlepagecolor}
\noindent
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo.jpg}\\[-1em]
\color{white}
\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{1.3\textwidth}{1pt}}
\par
\noindent
\textbf{\textsf{UniversitätsKlinikum}} \textcolor{namecolor}{\textsf{Heidelberg}}
\vfill
\noindent
{\huge \textsf{Handbuch 1.3}}
\vskip\baselineskip
\noindent
\textsf{August 2008}
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry % restores the geometry
\nopagecolor% Use this to restore the color pages to white
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}
```

There are several things to improve like may be using minipages, etc. An update as suggested by Harish Kumar is to use the `geometry` package as shown above, which is indeed better than my previous answer.

Comment: Check [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85989/26514) for further materials based on this one.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `\rule{width}{height}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,demo]{report} %% Remove demo in your file.
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{titlepage}

\pagecolor{blue}
\noindent
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo.jpg}\\[-1em]
\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{1.3\textwidth}{1pt}}
\par
\noindent
This is the title
\end{titlepage}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ouch, this hurts in the eyes! :-)

Comment: @Speravir Sorry! I went by OP's choice and code! `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

`\hrulefill` inserts a horizontal line.

What do you mean by the right position? If you want to align text, you can use the environments `flushleft`, `center`, `flushright`. So that would be

```
\begin{flushright}
    this text appears on the right of the page
\end{flushright}
```

also, if you want to print the title, you would simply say `\maketitle`, though you have to fill in the fields of the title (e.g. `author`, `title`, `date`) at any point in the document before you say `\maketitle` (usually in the preamble). So in your case you could say

```
\title{TITLE}


\begin{titlepage}

    \maketitle

\end{titlepage}
```

to print TITLE on your title page.