# "Title page" for section

Tags: sectioning, titles

I want to modify the section headers. Every time I create a new section, I want a simple card (something similar to a title page: something like the first answer on this question [Creating a titlepage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85870/creating-a-titlepage)) to be inserted.

Is there a package that already lets me do this, or do I have to muddle around with the code? Any pointers in the right direction would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the site! A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) will help us out greatly, since some document classes (e.g. `memoir`) have this functionality built-in, while others (e.g. `article`) would require a package such as [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) to be used. A mock-up (MS Paint or similar) of what you're looking for would also be very helpful, to gauge which packages would be best to use.

Comment: I guess you can always go `\newpage \section{My section}\cleardoubleemptypage`

Comment: So you want that doing \section{A section title} creates a new decorated page with the title "A section title" on it and the text (the contents for the section) would then begin on the next page. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possibility using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package; adjust the settings according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{RGB}{0,65,120}

\newcommand\sectionbreak{\clearpage}
\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {%
    \pagecolor{titlepagecolor}\thispagestyle{empty}%
    \normalfont\Huge\bfseries\color{white}\filcenter\titlerule[2pt]\vskip5pt%
  }
  {\thesection}
  {10pt}
  {}
  [{\vskip2pt\titlerule[2pt]\sectionbreak\nopagecolor}]

\begin{document}

\section*{Test unnumbered section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Test numbered section}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]